# How do I make Vim status line position in OSX the same as Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, vim

In my OSX box, I want to see the same cursor details that I see down in right-corner of my Ubuntu vim.

In my ubuntu box, this status line (maybe it isn't technically the "vim status line", I don't know) shows by default, and is on the same line and to the right of the command-line (i.e. what shows up after typing ":").

In my OSX box, I can only get the status line to show up above the command-line via something like:

```
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ [FORMAT=%{&ff}]\ [TYPE=%Y]\ [POS=%l,%v][%p%%]\ %{strftime(\"%d/%m/%y\ -\ %H:%M\")}
set laststatus=2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
:set ruler
```

Comment: Yep, that was exactly what I needed.  I realized it shortly after posting my question, hence answering it myself :) I'll give you the right answer though. Thanks for the reply

Comment: i've tried it on 2 macbook, it doesn't work..

Comment: i find out the reason, set paste reset the value of set ruler

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I missed this while reading documentation, but `set ruler` is the option I was looking for.

Comment: Discovered this by pasting a "recommended" vim setup into my ~/.vimrc file, and all of a sudden, that feature was there. Clever vim folk.